# Как на Python в aiogram можно было писать скрипт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, exec

Как на Python в aiogram можно было писать скрипт прямо в боте?
Допустим пишешь команду и потом вводишь скрипт и он выполняется в боте и отправляется в бота но при всё при этом бот асинхронный.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Ну eval() это же только счёт

Comment: Нет это любой питон код

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать *eval()*

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def date_handler(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(eval(msg.text))
```